# % Operator (multiple for loops)

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm after help using the % operator, my objective is to change the colour of an object within a loop depending on the iteration of the loop.

The first loop it will set it to red, on the second loop it will be yellow, on third loop will be blue and the fourth will be green and this will be repeated 50 times.

I am very new to this so any simple explanations would be really helpful :)

Thank you.

Comment: You really should post some code so we can see what you have tried so far. SO is not going to write code for you and it's no place for 'just' questions to be answered. Edit: Though you'll probably not have the time to edit your question as this will be getting downvoted to nowhere.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: *"The first loop it will set it to red..."* Do you mean *loop* or *iteration*? The whole thing is a loop; each pass through it is an iteration.

Comment: Run `for (var i=0; i < 50; i++) console.log(i, i % 4);` and you will see the repeating pattern.

Comment: @AlexK. Symbolic (-1) for missing curly brackets! Because I like curly brackets!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple snippet

```
var colors = ["red", "yellow","blue", "green"];
for(var i=0; i<50; i++){
   var myColorIndex = i % 4;
   var myColor = colors[myCOlorIndex];
   // now do whatever you want with myColor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) and [clearInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) after the 50th time. Save the colors in a array and get the `x%4` element

```js
var div = document.getElementById('id')
var x = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function () {

   div.style.backgroundColor = ['red','green','blue','yellow'][x%4]

   if (++x === 50) {
       window.clearInterval(interval);
   }
}, 1000);
```

```css
#id{
  width:200px,
  height:300px
  }
```

```html
<div id = "id"></div>
```